# how to correctly call std::lower_bound()?

Tags: c++, arrays, std

I'm plotting a data file with two columns (frequency and voltage) and I need to look for the closest value to a given value `val`. The thing is that my data behaves like a gaussian, so there are two values that satisfies that, above and below a max value. First I get each column in the data file into a `vector` array, having that I defined this function for finding those values

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>

typedef std::vector <double> vector;

vector posi(vector vec, int ref, double val);

int main(void){

  //define a custom volt vector here e.g vector volt{...};
  auto auxvmax = std::max_element(volt.begin(), volt.end());
  int posvmax = auxvmax - volt.begin();//this is what I take as ref value
  
  double val = 0.7;
  vector fpos(2, 0.0);
  fpos = posi(volt, posvmax, val);
  double auxf_1 = fpos[0];
  double auxf_2 = fpos[1];
  std::cout << "closest value to " << val << " are " << volt[auxf_1] << " below and " << volt[auxf_2] << " above\n";
return 0;
}

vector posi(vector vec, int ref, double val){

  vector posvec(2, 0.0);
  auto pos1 = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + ref, val);
  auto pos2 = std::lower_bound(vec.begin() + ref, vec.end(), val);

  double val1a = *(pos1 - 1.0);
  double val1b = *pos1;
  double val2a = *(pos2 - 1.0);
  double val2b = *pos2;

  if(fabs(val - val1a) < fabs(val - val1b)){
    posvec[0] = pos1 - vec.begin() - 1;
  }
  if(fabs(val - val1a) > fabs(val1b)){
    posvec[0] = pos1 - vec.begin();
  }
  if(fabs(val - val2a) < fabs(val - val2b)){
    posvec[1] = pos2 - vec.begin() - 1;
  }
  if(fabs(val - val2a) > fabs(val - val2b)){
    posvec[1] = pos2 - vec.begin();
  }

  return posvec;
}
```

Let me explain how and why I constructed the function like this, so you can tell me where am I wrong.

Basically, I'm trying to use `std::lower_bound()` in two "regions" of the vector in which the values are, this is so that the program looks for only one closest value in each region, I know where the max value is (in `main` function, via `std::max_element()`) so I can easily make the split. `ref` is the position (iterator) where the max value is allocated in `vec` vector, so it is supposed to get the closest value to `val` above and below that `ref` position.

Next, it only makes sure that the value is the closest, considering the smallest next value to `val` (default value given by `std::lower_bound())` and the previous one, getting the closest in each case (region). Finally, the position in the vector of each value is stored into `posvec` vector (since I have to get the frequencies where voltage is the closest to `val`, so I don't need the voltage value but his position, since freq and volt make pairs).

when I compile it gives no errors, no warnings, but the closest values are not the closest. I found (cppreference) that the array that `std::lower_bound()` gets must be sorted from low to max, and my data is sorted from lowest to max below the max value, and max to lowest above max value, so there should be a problem with the above data, but -**and here is my question**- why am I not getting the closest value even with the data below? am I not getting something with the `std::lower_bound()` behavior?, is it maybe something when I use the if statements? the output, printing an example voltage vector as well is below

[image: here]

Here you can see the "closest" values are indeed the furthest.

Thanks for your help in advance.

EDIT: asked in comments, the output is

```
closest values to 0.7 are 0.485437 below, and 0.320388 above
0.485437
0.500971
0.524272
0.543689
0.563107
0.594175
0.617476
0.648544
0.679612
0.71068
0.741748
0.786408
0.825243
0.864078
0.893204
0.932039
0.961165
0.980583
0.990291
1
0.990291
0.961165
0.941748
0.893204
0.854369
0.805825
0.757282
0.708738
0.669903
0.621359
0.582524
0.547573
0.512621
0.481553
0.454369
0.427184
0.403883
0.384466
0.361165
0.341748
0.320388
```

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: `lower_bound` only works correctly on a sorted sequence.  Doesn't sound like that describes your data.

Comment: @MarkRansom but why it doesn't work even with the data from 0.485437 to 1? it is sorted how is it supossed to be with ```lower_bound``` right?

Comment: Can you post your output as text?  The image is difficult to read (very small type).  Highlight the text, copy to the clipboard (Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Insert) then paste into your question.

Comment: It doesn't have to be sorted per se, just partitioned with respect to the element you're looking for (i.e. all elements less than it must precede all elements not-less than it).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat is there any way to deal with it in my case without creating new vectors?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't think that's true, doesn't it use a binary search?  Any out-of-order elements will cause it to fail on occasion.

Comment: @MarkRansom It won't notice them being out of order since it only compares them with the target value. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) on the range requirements.

Comment: @CosmeticMichu I think your ranges are fine, you just need to pass `std::greater<>{}` as the comparator to the *second* `lower_bound`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank you, I think I learned something important about binary search today.